# How to check if a string contains some part of another string in C#?

Tags: c#, string

```
String1 = "12345"
String2 = "12abc"
```

I want to return `true` if `String1` contains some part of `String2`. In this example String2 has "12" which exists in String1. So For example `String1.Contains(String2)` should return `true`.

How Can I make such `'Contains'` Function?

Comment: Does `xxxxx12` and `12abc` results in a match as well? If so; you'll need to check for all possible substrings, which will be very slow.

Comment: Does `"".Contains("12abc")` return true?

Comment: @Stefan One just needs to check if any character exists in the other string (since they didn't say how long the substring must be)

Comment: @Rob, ah, yes, good point.

Comment: If `String1` contains a part of `String2`, it will contain all `char` of this part. Check all `char` of `String2` in `String1`. How to do? See Rob's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You haven't told us the minimum length of the matching string, so I'll assuming the minimum length is `1`.

Therefore, you can write:

```
String1.Any(c => String2.Contains(c))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative would be using Intersect. This will help you to set certain "threshold" of the number of similar elements:

```
string String1 = "12345"
string String2 = "12abc"

var result = String1.ToCharArray().Intersect(String2.ToCharArray()).ToList();

if (result.Count > 0) //to check if there is any intersect
```

Just change > 0 to > N (N is positive integer: 1, 2, 3,... etc) to set the threshold.

Answer (score 3):

You can check presence of common substring between two string using this way

```
public static bool IsPresent(string str1, string str2)
        {

            int[,] num = new int[str1.Length, str2.Length];
            int maxLen = 0;
            int lastSubsBegin = 0;
            StringBuilder sequenceBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (str1[i] != str2[j])
                        num[i, j] = 0;
                    else
                    {
                        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                            num[i, j] = 1;
                        else
                            num[i, j] = 1 + num[i - 1, j - 1];

                        if (num[i, j] > maxLen)
                        {
                            maxLen = num[i, j];
                            int thisSubsBegin = i - num[i, j] + 1;
                            if (lastSubsBegin == thisSubsBegin)
                            {
                                // If the current LCS is the same as the last time this block ran
                                sequenceBuilder.Append(str1[i]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                // Reset the string builder if a different LCS is found
                                lastSubsBegin = thisSubsBegin;
                                sequenceBuilder.Length = 0;
                                sequenceBuilder.Append(str1.Substring(lastSubsBegin, (i + 1) - lastSubsBegin));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (sequenceBuilder.Length != 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is useful link
http://www.datavoila.com/projects/text/longest-common-substring-of-two-strings.html

Answer (score 2):

You could do this.

```
string String1 = "12345";
string String2 = "12abc";

var subs = from i in Enumerable.Range(0, String2.Length)
    from l in Enumerable.Range(1, String2.Length - i)
    let part = String2.Substring(i, l)
    select part;

if(subs.Any(s=> String1.Contains(s)))
{
    // contains.
}
```

That's valid point (from comments), even single character can match between two strings.

```
if(String1.Any(s=>String2.Contains(s)))
{
    // contains 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use IndexOfAny:

```
string string1 = "12345";
string string2 = "12abc";

var isFound = string1.IndexOfAny(string2.ToCharArray()) >= 0;

var firstOccurrenceIdx = string1.IndexOfAny(string2.ToCharArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you what to change the number of minimum number of characters that must be in both strings, you could do something like the following.  Change the charsToCompare constant to be the minimum number of shared values to work.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World".ContainsSubstring("Henry"));
      Console.WriteLine("Hello World".ContainsSubstring("Hank"));
      Console.WriteLine("12345".ContainsSubstring("12abc"));
   }
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
   public static bool ContainsSubstring(this string str, string compareValue)
   {
      const int charsToCompare = 2;
      var subString = compareValue.Substring(0, Math.Min(charsToCompare, compareValue.Length));
      if (str.Contains(subString))
      {
         return true;
      }
      else if (compareValue.Length > charsToCompare)
      {
         return str.ContainsSubstring(compareValue.Substring(1));
      }
      return false;
   }
}
```

You can play around with it on dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ie1eLx

Answer (score 1):

You could check for the levenshtein distance as outlined here: [http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26805.c-calculating-percentage-similarity-of-2-strings.aspx]

Depending on how similar you want the strings to be you can change the check on the CalculateSimilarity.

```
bool AreSimilar(string a, string b)
{
    return CalculateSimilarity(a, b) > .25;
}

/// <summary>
/// Calculate percentage similarity of two strings
/// <param name="source">Source String to Compare with</param>
/// <param name="target">Targeted String to Compare</param>
/// <returns>Return Similarity between two strings from 0 to 1.0</returns>
/// </summary>
double CalculateSimilarity(string source, string target)
{
    if ((source == null) || (target == null)) return 0.0;
    if ((source.Length == 0) || (target.Length == 0)) return 0.0;
    if (source == target) return 1.0;

    int stepsToSame = ComputeLevenshteinDistance(source, target);
    return (1.0 - ((double)stepsToSame / (double)Math.Max(source.Length, target.Length)));
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the number of steps required to transform the source string
/// into the target string.
/// </summary>
int ComputeLevenshteinDistance(string source, string target)
{
    if ((source == null) || (target == null)) return 0;
    if ((source.Length == 0) || (target.Length == 0)) return 0;
    if (source == target) return source.Length;

    int sourceWordCount = source.Length;
    int targetWordCount = target.Length;

    // Step 1
    if (sourceWordCount == 0)
        return targetWordCount;

    if (targetWordCount == 0)
        return sourceWordCount;

    int[,] distance = new int[sourceWordCount + 1, targetWordCount + 1];

    // Step 2
    for (int i = 0; i <= sourceWordCount; distance[i, 0] = i++) ;
    for (int j = 0; j <= targetWordCount; distance[0, j] = j++) ;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sourceWordCount; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= targetWordCount; j++)
        {
            // Step 3
            int cost = (target[j - 1] == source[i - 1]) ? 0 : 1;

            // Step 4
            distance[i, j] = Math.Min(Math.Min(distance[i - 1, j] + 1, distance[i, j - 1] + 1), distance[i - 1, j - 1] + cost);
        }
    }

    return distance[sourceWordCount, targetWordCount];
}
```

Comment: ComputeLevenshteinDistance() does not work as expected. all 3 checks in the beginning are all done wrong. `if (source == target) return 0` and the other 2 should not be 0 unless they are both null/empty.